# Do you pay to Touch-and-Go?

Tags: runways, touch-and-go

I understand you pay to land at an airfield, but do you pay to Touch-and-Go?

Pilots will often practice many Touch-and-Go's at an airfield, are you billed for each one (assuming you pay something to use the airfield's resources for the Touch-and-Go procedure).

How are you charged if you don't do a full-stop at the field (practicing at another airfield different from your home base)?

Comment: Which country are you asking about?

Comment: @slookabill I'm most interested in US, but if it differs elsewhere, that would be interesting to know as well.

Comment: Very few airfields charge for landing, essentially just major commercial ones that don't want private traffic.  Some will charge for overnight tiedowns, but most smaller ones are "free" in the sense that roads are free - that is, you're paying through gas taxes &c.

Comment: @jamesqf Is that true at private airfields (ones that allow GA but are not owned by the city, etc)? Private roads/bridges have tolls, so I'd assume it's the same, no?

Comment: Except for the largest airports, most airports in the US do not charge a landing fee. Santa Monica (KSMO) wants to shut down the airport and they currently charge small GA aircraft $7 for each landing or touch and go—even the ones based there. If you stop at an FBO, to drop off passengers or take a break, the FBO will usually charge you. Many airports have free parking at the restaurant or near the self-serve fuel pumps.

Comment: @SnakeDoc: AFAIK, most private fields are just that, private, so you should have prior permission from the owner before landing.  I suppose if they're associated with a resort or something, they might charge, but I've never encountered one myself.  But I do most of my flying in the western US, and to strips that are either dirt or if paved, have minimal facilities.  They seem to be owned by county, state, or Forest Service/BLM.

Comment: It really depends.  15 years ago at BWI there was no fee for touch and goes, even for aircraft that were not based there.  I'm not sure what their policy is currently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It varies.  Some airports charge by landing, others by operation (a series of landings if training).  Some charge through the FBO, who may waive the fee with fuel purchase.  Expect that multiple landings at BOS or JFK will result in multiple fees, often billed to the registered owner.  It was a while ago, but I did a series (about 12) of landings at BOS one night, and the owner/operator paid 25 dollars each. Someone told me recently that the fee was more like $65 now for a Cessna P210.

To be clear, call the airport and ask them, or check their web page, which may have their charges and rules on it.  And/or check with an FBO or two at the field.

Answer (score 3):

Its [address more or less in this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/22466/how-are-landing-fees-collected/22467#22467) but they will bill you by tail number (to the owner operator on file). Generally speaking for touch-and-gos the landing fee is only applied once a day so you can do as many as you like and only pay the fee once (in my experience) as an example you can find the fee structure and payment info for [KPNE (where I fly out of sometimes) here](http://regulations.phila-records.com/pdfs/Department%20of%20Commerce%20%20%20Division%20of%20Aviation%20Regs.%2004-17-17.pdf).

Comment: Wow, $5 is a lot less than I expected. The landing fees for GA are probably the cheapest part.

Comment: I don't completely understand your comments about KPNE. In the other question you mentioned a \$5 landing fee paid at the FBO, which sounds normal enough. But your answer here makes it sounds like they charge you \$5 just to do touch and goes, even if you never do a full stop or use the ramp/FBO. Is that correct?

Comment: I have always flown out of there and paid at the FBO but I belive if you do Touch-and-gos they send a bill to the aircraft owner/operator after the fact. The regulation does not specify full stop landings vs touch-and-go for the billing. At the other FBO/Flight schools I have rented from at uncontrolled fields I have seen them receive bills for such operations.